# How to set a default value to a column in .Net 3.1 when I create my column

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

So I am using .Net 3.1, and I have the following class:

```
public Addresses{
        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public String Name {get; set;}
}
```

and I want to add a new Column to it like this

```
public Addresses{
        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public String Name {get; set;}
        public bool IsAddrLocal {get; set;}
}
```

but I want the new column `IsAddrLocal` to have a default value of True for all columns that have already been created in the database.

I tried adding doing this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyShippingAddress>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(x=>x.IsAddrLocal).HasDefaultValue(true);

            });
}
```

however it would cause my values to be always true (even the new ones being entered) so I tried to make the field nullable

```
public Addresses{
        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public String Name {get; set;}
        public bool? IsAddrLocal {get; set;}
}
```

Which would cause old addresses to have the value NULL assigned to them and only new ones have the True value assigned to them.

I tried adding a constructor to the class and making the field non-nullable again

```
        public Addresses()
        {
            IsAddrLocal= true;
        }
```

but this would cause old addresses to get a value of False and new ones a value of True.

How can I make the default value of this field True for new and old values unless later on a User sends a request to update the field for a specific row to false?

Comment: "however it would cause my values to be always true (even the new ones being entered)". what is the issue with this. you wanted this right ?. and default value will be used only if you don't provide value while creating instance. so i don't see any issue with your first solution.

Comment: @CodingMytra The issues is for the new values being entered, a value for ```IsAddrLocal``` is being sent by the client and received by my function however it is being overwitted by the default value of the column. I only want the old values in the database to have this default value of true.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, your question is that when adding the IsAddrLocal property, you want to set the default value to `true`, then the new address without set the IsAddrLocal property and the existed Address in the database should also set the default value. But if the new address has the IsAddrLocal property, it should store its value.

To solve this issue, you can try to use the following method:
Assume you have create the Address table with two columns: AddressID and Name, and insert some value.

1. Add the `IsAddrLocal` property in the Addresses model.

   ```
    public class Addresses
    {
        [Key]
        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsAddrLocal { get; set; } = true; //set the default value.
    }
   ```

   [Note]There is no need to use the HasDefaultValue to set the default value. Remove this part of code from the OnModelCreating method.
2. Execute the `Add-Migration adddefaultvaluerul` command to generate the migration file.
3. Open the adddefaultvaluerul migration file, in the Up method, change the defaultvalue from `false` to `true`.

   [image]
4. Execute the `update-database` comment, then you can see the existed Address has been set the default value.

   [image]
5. Then, when you insert new address, like this:

   ```
        var items = new List<Addresses>()
        {
            new Addresses(){ Name="A1", IsAddrLocal=false },
            new Addresses(){ Name="A2"},
            new Addresses(){ Name="A3" ,IsAddrLocal=false },
        };
        _dbcontext.Addresses.AddRange(items);
        _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
   ```

   the output as below:

   [image]